# Integrate Flutter into existing SWT Java Project

Tags: java, flutter, swt, flutter-web

I would like to help my company making a transaction **from SWT to Flutter**.
The idea is to integrate into the existing SWT project, single Flutter applications.

I thought I could achieve that using **Browser**.
I created a demo flutter web project and hosted [here](http://java-flutter.epizy.com/#/)
Then I tried to visualize the website using the following snippet.

```
public class Main{
  public static void main(String[] args) {
      Display display = new Display();
      final Shell shell = new Shell(display);
      shell.setText("Browser Example");
      shell.setSize(1200, 800);
    
      final Browser browser = new Browser(shell, SWT.NONE);
      browser.setBounds(0, 0, 1200, 800);
    
      shell.open();
      // http://time-time.net/timer/digital-clock.php
      browser.setUrl("http://java-flutter.epizy.com/#/");
      while (!shell.isDisposed()) {
          if (!display.readAndDispatch())
              display.sleep();
      }
      display.dispose();
  }
}
```

But when I run the application I can only see a white screen and no error is logged.
If I right-click and view the source code, I can correctly see the source code of the flutter web page.

Besides, the snippet is correct, because if I replace the flutter URL with "http://time-time.net/timer/digital-clock.php", I can correctly visualize the website.

**Do you have any idea what I can do for solving my issue?**

Your proposed solution can be how to solve the problem using the Browser component, but it can be also a completely different one. For me, the importance is just to focus on the **goal of integrating small Flutter applications inside an old existing SWT java project**.

Comment: Running this on macOS does give an error - "Page load failed with error: The resource could not be loaded because the App Transport Security policy requires the use of a secure connection." or using https - "Page load failed with error: An SSL error has occurred and a secure connection to the server cannot be made."

Comment: But if I try to go on [https://java-flutter.epizy.com/](https://java-flutter.epizy.com/), it fails saying that the site can’t provide a secure connection. So even if I add a secure connection on my Browser (that I am not sure how to do), I will still not be able to load the website. I mean, why Chrome can see it even without a secure connection, and the SWT Browser cannot?